# A fine point of grammar: which verb is riflessivo?

Tags: verbs, grammar

I understand the meaning of the following sentence, but need to know which verb is the riflessivo:

> Mi lasciai accecare dai miei sentimenti.

Is this an example of lasciarsi or accecarsi?

Comment: In the infinitive, one would say “lasciarsi accecare”; the phrase “lasciarsi andare” is very common.

Answer (score 4):

At the [voice "lasciare" of Treccani dictionary](https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/lasciare) you can check that "lasciarsi" is indeed a reflexive verb, followed by an infinitive. Such dictionary gives you some examples of use:

> Seguito da un infinito (o da che e il cong.), è per lo più sinon. di *permettere*, con molta varietà di accezioni, toni e articolazioni: [...] Rifl. (col *si* riferito all’infinito): *lasciarsi ingannare, lasciarsi trasportare dall’ira; si lasciò morire di fame; non si lascia menare per il naso da nessuno*; talora presuppone una certa resistenza: *si lasciò convincere; alla fine s’è lasciato piegare*.

You can also find the phrase "lasciarsi andare" given by @egreg in his comment:

> nel rifl., *lasciarsi andare*, abbandonarsi, cedere a un sentimento: *làsciati andare, ti reggo io; mi sto lasciando andare a un nuovo amore*⁷; fig., in senso morale, cedere al vizio, a una colpa, abbandonarsi senza resistenza a una condotta riprovevole (con altro senso fig., seguito da complemento, non guardarsi dal fare una cosa: *s’è lasciato andare a confidenze un po’ pericolose*).

So, in your sentence, the reflexive verb is "lasciarsi".